# merging gcs files and pasting to another gcs bucket using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

i am able to read the files from gcs bucket, but i am not able to merge the sample files and write it to another gcs location.

i have to merge all the files in one folder of gcs bucket and move that merged file to other gcs bucket location using python.
ex: gs://hello/test
test contains 5 files and the contnet of all 5 files to be merged and moved to another folder say test1.

i tried to move one file from one gcs to other, but the use case is merge all the files in one folder and move the merged file to other gcs bucket.

Comment: Hi @sam. Please share your code to show what you've tried and what is failing. It sounds like you would need to download all files in a bucket, read them, join them in memory, and then write back to GCS.

Comment: Can you share how you merge your file? WIth Compose? by code? If so, share it!

Comment: And it can't hurt to formulate an *explicit* question. That eases to answer more precisely ;-)